# How can I import AdTree and BfTree Algorithm to Weka App?

Tags: weka

I want to use AdTree and BfTree algorithm on my datas but  I could not find that algorithms in my Weka app. Is there anyone who knows to implement that to weka ?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do that you have to open Weka and Select Tools > Package Manager.
On the "Package Manager" go to "Package Search" and look for:

1. "bestFirstTree" and
2. "AlternatingDecisionTrees" (Classification) or
3. "AlternatingModelTrees" (Regression).

Don't forget to select it (so it becomes blue) and then click Install !